# Como inserir valor no atributo html com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Uma dúvida

Como inserir um valor dentro de um atributo href="" com javascript

Answer (score 1):

basta você obter o link e depois setar o valor no atributo href, segue um exemplo do código:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Teste</a>

var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.href = 'http://google.com'
```